# Tennis match - combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

A group organizing a faculty-student tennis match must match four faculty volunteers to four of the $13$ students who volunteered to be in the match.

In how many ways can they do this?

Is it just simply $13\choose4$ since the teachers is $4\choose4$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line up the faculty members in order of seniority. The first faculty member can choose her opponent in $13$ ways. For **each** of these ways, the second most senior faculty member can choose her opponent in $12$ ways, and so on, for a total of $(13)(12)(11)(10)$.

Answer (score 3):

You can choose 4 volunteers out of 13 students in $C_{13}^4$ ways, however, matching those to 4 professors can be done in $A_4 = 4!$ ways, so the answer is the $C_{13}^4 4!$

Answer (score 1):

Does order matter here?  For example does it matter which of the picked students play which teachers?  If so, then you are missing a 4! factor since there are 24 ways to pair up the 4 people.

Answer (score 1):

you have $13\choose4$ ways to choose the student, but then you have $4!$ ways to assign each faculty to a student opponent.

So the overall number you are looking for is ${ 13\choose4}4!$, which is $13*12*11*10$ (number of arrangements).